# Why am i getting a "'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Objty'" error in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating a program where the user has to identify certain chords. I'm using SDL to render text and shapes onto a GUI and SDL_Mixer to load sounds. The program will require the user to play a sound and guess the sound that was played using a series of options. The rest of the program works fine. However, the issue occurred once i tried to implement a way to load and work with sounds. All of the code below is encapsulated in a class.

I tried commenting out certain parts of the code and i found that the error occurs when i try to add the sounds to the vector using emplace_back(). The error occurs at line 881 of a file called xmemory0. This is the code where the error occurs "_Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);".

This code has it's access specifier defined as private

```
//Container to hold the sound data

std::vector<Sound*>Sounds;

//Container to hold the randomly selected sounds;
std::vector<Sound*> randomSounds;


Sound* aMinor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* aMajor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* a7{ new Sound{} };
Sound* aMajor7{ new Sound{} };
Sound* cMajor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* dMajor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* dMinor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* eMajor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* eMinor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* eMinor7{ new Sound{} };
Sound* eMajor7{ new Sound{} };
Sound* fMajor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* fMinor{ new Sound{} };
Sound* gMajor{ new Sound{} };

//These are the pointers for the randomly selected sounds
Sound* randomSoundLeft;
Sound* randomSoundMiddle;
Sound* randomSoundRight;

//Pointer for the sound which the user will play
Sound* currentPlayingSound;
```

This code is defined within a 'load data' method

```
//Add sounds to vector
Sounds.emplace_back(aMinor, aMajor, aMajor7,
a7,cMajor, dMajor, dMinor,
eMajor, eMajor7, eMinor, eMinor7,
fMajor, fMinor, gMajor);


//Load sounds
if (!aMinor->loadSound("Chords/A_minor.wav")
or !aMajor->loadSound("Chords/A_major.wav")
or !a7->loadSound("Chords/A_7.wav")
or !aMajor7->loadSound("Chords/A_major7.wav")
or !cMajor->loadSound("Chords/C_major.wav")
or !dMajor->loadSound("Chords/D_major.wav")
or !dMinor->loadSound("Chords/D_minor.wav")
or !eMajor->loadSound("Chords/E_major.wav")
or !eMajor7->loadSound("Chords/E_major7.wav")
or !eMinor->loadSound("Chords/E_minor.wav")
or !eMinor7->loadSound("Chords/E_minor7.wav")
or !fMajor->loadSound("Chords/F_major.wav")
or !fMinor->loadSound("Chords/F_minor.wav")
or !gMajor->loadSound("Chords/G_major.wav")) {

printf("One or more sounds couldn't be loaded! %s\n", Mix_GetError());
}


//Set chord names
aMinor->setChordName("A Minor", black, renderer, mediumFont);
aMajor->setChordName("A Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
a7->setChordName("A7", black, renderer, mediumFont);
aMajor7->setChordName("A Major7", black, renderer, mediumFont);
cMajor->setChordName("C Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
dMajor->setChordName("D Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
dMinor->setChordName("D Minor", black, renderer, mediumFont);
eMajor->setChordName("E Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
eMajor7->setChordName("E Major7", black, renderer, mediumFont);
eMinor->setChordName("E Minor", black, renderer, mediumFont);
eMinor7->setChordName("E Minor7", black, renderer, mediumFont);
fMajor->setChordName("F Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
fMinor->setChordName("F Minor", black, renderer, mediumFont);
gMajor->setChordName("G Major", black, renderer, mediumFont);
```

This code is defined within the 'update' method

```
//Used to prevent this section running in the normal game loop
if (rounds == changeLevel) {

//Randomly choose sounds
randomSoundLeft = Sounds.at(rand() % Sounds.size());
randomSoundMiddle = Sounds.at(rand() % Sounds.size());
randomSoundRight = Sounds.at(rand() % Sounds.size());

//Create a new container and add the possible choices to the container
randomSounds.emplace_back(randomSoundLeft, randomSoundMiddle, randomSoundRight);

//Randomly chose one of the options to be the sound that the user plays
currentPlayingSound = randomSounds.at(rand() % randomSounds.size());

++changeLevel;


}
```

I expected the chords containing a name and a sound to be added to the vector without any issues. However, i have this error: 
Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Objty'

Comment: `Sound* aMinor{ new Sound{} };` <-- I'm pretty sure none of these have to be pointers... (`Sound* randomSoundLeft;` i would initialize this to nullptr just to be safe)

Comment: Why all the dynamic allocation?

Comment: And *where* do you get the error? On which of the lines you show? And can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with a comment on the line that causes the error.

Comment: Why all the irrelevant code? Provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Wow, please learn about loops. There's no reason to write such walls of code.

Comment: "`_Objty`" is a *really bad* symbol name. Any symbol starting with underscore and followed by a capital letter is *reserved for the implementation* and not one you can use.

Comment: Looks like a poor error message. I’m guessing emplace_back is causing problems. EDIT: please read the documentation on emplace_back, if that wasn’t clear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- `_Objty` is an internal name in the library implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emplace_back method is to emplace one element. It takes arbirtary number of arguments as all of them are passed to constructor of a single element.

To add many elements at once you need to use method that accepts iterator range or initializer list.

This should work:

```
Sounds.insert(Sounds.end(), {aMinor, aMajor, aMajor7,
a7,cMajor, dMajor, dMinor,
eMajor, eMajor7, eMinor, eMinor7,
fMajor, fMinor, gMajor});
```

If your version of compiler does not support initializer lists, this would work:

```
Sound* inserted[] = {aMinor, aMajor, aMajor7,
a7,cMajor, dMajor, dMinor,
eMajor, eMajor7, eMinor, eMinor7,
fMajor, fMinor, gMajor};
Sounds.insert(Sounds.end(), inserted, inserted+sizeof(inserted)/sizeof(inserted[0]));
```